# Create a text layer in psd

Tags: command-line, gimp, photoshop

Is there a command line to create a text layer (PSD format)?

I checked `gimp` but wasn't able to do it.
My expected output is a `.psd` file with one layer of text "hello world".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image Magick can do this.

Basic example to create a PSD file with `hello world` in text.

`convert label:"hello world" example.psd`

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/  for all the available options.